# How can I copy this knockout observable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to add a "default" object to my Knockout `observableArray`.  The way my code stands currently, I end up adding the exact same object to the array instead of a new instance of the object.  I tried using jQuery's `.extend()`, but, that didn't work out so I am looking for input.

Here is a demonstration to show my problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/2c8Fx/

**HTML**:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: People">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
</div>

<button type="button" data-bind="click: AddPerson">Add Person</button>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

**Script**:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.EmptyPerson = ko.mapping.fromJS({Name: null, Age: null});
    self.People = ko.observableArray([self.EmptyPerson]);

    self.AddPerson = function() {
      self.People.push(self.EmptyPerson);  
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

This doesn't work because the `observableArray` is actually holding a reference to the same object for each index.

What's the best way to create a new instance of my Knockout object?

Comment: @jonhopkins - That would result in an error when the `AddPerson` method is called.

Comment: @jonhopkins - No worries, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.People = ko.observableArray();

    self.AddPerson = function() {
      self.People.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({Name: null, Age: null}));  
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I did this and it works like you think it would. I hope this helps.

Check out a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2c8Fx/1/)

Comment: I suppose this could work with a small tweak (I need a default value in my array so I could move the `mapping.fromJS` call to a method that just returns the Knockout object).

Comment: Is there anything that is keeping you from accepting this as the answer? I answered your question as it was stated.

Comment: Looks like someone is a little anxious for points!  I like to wait more than 20 minutes to see if other answers come in and offer other solutions.